# Xamarin iOS: iPhone simulator cannot access keychain with Wildcard Provisioning Profile

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, keychain, provisioning

I recently downgraded the Xamarin-iOS package to 15.0.0.6.pkg to fix this known issue:

[How to overcome "Please select a valid device before running the application." on a paired with Mac Visual Studio on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65311087/how-to-overcome-please-select-a-valid-device-before-running-the-application-o)

The fix worked for the connection to an iPhone. But since I need to access the filesystem, it's easier to do it with the simulator.

The app needs access to the phones keychain to start correctly. When I tried to start with the simulator I got a NullReference Exception because the keychain could obviously not be accessed.

The provisioning profile used was:
**Provisioning Profile: "VS: WildCard Development"**

I have no idea what to do next. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Did you enable KeyChain access in your Entitlements.plist? and if Entitlements.plist is assigned to your Custom  Entitlements in your Project Build / iOS Bundle Signing?

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time. I did both, actually. After a long time, I figured out what the problem was: the keychain record that I was trying to access did not exist yet, because the Simulator was a new instance all of a sudden. So it simply wasn't set yet... Fixed the code accordingly.

Comment: @hansoolow, I have the same issue how do you fix your issue?