# How to solve 'Please select a valid device before running the application.' for Android in Visual Studio Preview 2022?

Tags: android, visual-studio-2022, maui

After migrating my project from Xamarin.Forms to .NET MAUI as instructed by this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/migrate), I could deploy it to Android Emulator just fine, but when I pushed it to a new branch in Gitlab, clone it to a new local folder and deploy it to Android Emulator, I got this error from the cloned project solution's Output window. The build was successful, but not so for deploy.

```
1>------ Deploy started: Project: x.Android, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Please select a valid device before running the application.
1>Deploy failed
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

My OS is Windows 10 and I use Visual Studio Community 2022 Preview (ver. 17.3.0 Preview 1.1). My Android Emulator is Pixel 5 - API 31.

I'm aware that similar questions have already been asked multiple times, but most of them were dedicated for iOS and I couldn't find the solution for Android. I've tried rebuilding my solution, unchecking and rechecking all the checkboxes in Configuration Manager, updating Android SDK, factory reset my emulator, and restart Adb server, but none of these worked.

I've also checked my selected emulator and from the looks of it, VS 2022 Preview detected my emulator just fine
[as shown by this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRohw.png)

Outside of this project solution, VS 2022 Preview can run .NET MAUI projects without problem, with my Android Emulator's name replacing the "Start" button. Additionally, I can also switch between two Android Emulators (before I deleted one) when I open natural .NET MAUI project solutions, something I can't do for this migrated project. The dropdown just closed without doing anything, with check mark on the left of my emulator's name not moving to the newly-chosen emulator.

I'm not sure whether it's caused by VS 2022 Preview, my emulator, or my migrated project. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to overcome "Please select a valid device before running the application." on a paired with Mac Visual Studio on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65311087/how-to-overcome-please-select-a-valid-device-before-running-the-application-o)

Comment: I'm afraid not. I've already looked it up but it didn't help my case.

Comment: You can try to install android studio and start android emulator there.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. What resolved it for me was setting `<SingleProject>True</SingleProject>` in the Android .csproj file.

I could not find much documentation on the issue. Apparently, this tag is meant to declare that the project is using MAUI's Single Project philosophy instead of Xamarin.Forms. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/single-project

Even though my project came from a Xamarin.Forms migration, this tag seems to work.

Comment: Thank you! Adding this property to my Android project immediately allowed my local device and emulators to show up and be deployed to. Literally no other changes were needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in my case Visual Studio did not add the .csproj.user file for my project automatically
I had to add this file to the git (and also edit it because I had different emulators on the other machine).